# problema con numpy

Tags: python, bucle-for, numpy

buenos dias. mi duda es la siguiente.

Teniendo una matrix X, tal que :

```
x = [
   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 3, 3],
   [4, 4, 4, 4]
]
```

Como podria iteral la matriz para calcular la media de los valores vecinos, sin recibir IndexErros?

```
MatrizConMedia[i, j] = (x[i, j-1] + x[i-1, j] + x[i, j+1] + x[i+1, j]) / 4
```

Mi primera idea era :

```
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
```

pero a la primera que coje un valor fuera de la matriz, en lugar de sustituirlo por un 0, me devuelve error directamente.
Muchisimas gracias a todos, y muchisimas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: La respuesta depende de la logica que debiese ocurrir ante esa condición de borde, debería ser tomado como 0? deberia caerse? deberia toamrse como el mismo valor que el borde? Por eso el programa se cae porque el comportamiento es indeterminado, ahi tu debes programar la logica ante estas condiciones de borde o al menos explicalas en tu pregunta dado que como lo expones sigue estando indeterminado el *que debería ocurrir* en esos casos.

Comment: Qué error devuelve? Por favor inclúyelo editando tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solucion es que verifiques los indices para que no intentes acceder a un sitio en el arreglo que no existe o que no es el que quieres.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
              [2, 2, 2, 2],
              [3, 3, 3, 3],
              [4, 4, 4, 4]])

print("Matrix\n{}".format(x))

MatrizConMedia = np.zeros(x.shape)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        if i > 0:
            MatrizConMedia[i, j] += x[i - 1, j]
        if i < x.shape[0] - 1:
            MatrizConMedia[i, j] += x[i + 1, j]
        if j > 0:
            MatrizConMedia[i, j] += x[i, j - 1]
        if j < x.shape[1] - 1:
            MatrizConMedia[i, j] += x[i, j + 1]
MatrizConMedia /= 4

print("Matrix de promedio de vecinos\n{}".format(MatrizConMedia))
```